How to handle environment configuration with Jenkins?
Hello everyone I am new to ci/cd and trying to build a go&postgresql application with multiple environments.

Development environment is a linux box with database running in a container

Test Environment: Openshift cluster

Prod Environment: Openshift cluster

Code Repo: GitHub: Branches DEV/TEST/PROD

CI/CD Tool: Jenkins

I can write specific Jenkinsfile for each branch and corresponding jobs in Jenkins. In this scenario:

I am putting environment configuration in the Jenkinsfile
I am making code changes manually for each branch



I don't want to have any environment configuration within the repo together with the code. I want to make the content of the branches identical as much as possible.
I tried to take the Jenkinsfile out and put it directly into the jenkins job as a pipeline script. Same script failed in this case.
I want to ask what is the correct method to pursue.

Should I put the Jenkinsfile together with the code?

how can i differentiate the content of this file in different branches when merging a branch into another. Put it in .gitignore and manage its content manually perhaps?
I can keep the configuration else where. For example dedicated database tables for each branch. But still I would need a different token in Jenkinsfile for each branch to be able to separate.


Should I put the Jenkinsfile in the job?


Is Jenkings the best tool in this case?

Well... It's actually quite hard to decide where to start from, as your setup and suggestions seem to be quite far from, and sometimes almost completely opposite to the industry standards. You might want to inform yourself more on the branching models, CI/CD, release management, configuration management, infrastructure as code, and configuration as code approaches before proceeding any further. At the current point this question doesn't seem to meet the StackOverflow guidelines because of many reasons at the same time.
